# Обтекание блоков со всех сторон

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, img

Необходимо сделать галерею. Все картинки имеют свои размеры, но при добавлении их на страницу, они уменьшаются до `width: 270px` и до пропорциональной ширины. Мне нужно, чтобы картинки обтекали друг друга, как это показано на 1ом скрине. У меня же, через флексы, не работает нормальное обтекание

```css
main .pictures {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
main .pictures img {
  display: flex;
  width: 270px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 0 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="pictures">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/01.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/02.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/03.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/04.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/05.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/06.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/07.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/08.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/09.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/10.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/11.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/12.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/13.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/14.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/15.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/16.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/17.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/18.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/19.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/20.jpg">
  <img src="assets/images/gallery/21.jpg">
</section>
```

[image: Как должно выглядеть]
[image: Как получилось у меня]

Comment: в вашем вопросе нет вопроса

Comment: только что исправил)

Comment: то что вы хотите достигается только средствами js , на css не возможно , смотрите в сторону masonry.js там есть мануал и прочее

Comment: [Seamless Responsive Photo Grid](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/).
На чистом CSS. Javascript в это примере используется только для загрузки рандомных изображений со стороннего сайта.
И [CSS wrap divs with different sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493380/css-wrap-divs-with-different-sizes). Два примера в ответе

Comment: еще как вариант masonry библиотека http://enkom.kiev.ua/masonry-reshenie-dlya-vyvoda.html

Comment: [Вот тут расписано как сделать такой вывод картинок](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/)

Answer (score 1):

вам нужен jquery плагин masonry, он воспроизводит такой еффект, подробнее вот тут http://masonry.desandro.com/