# Мозаичная верстка(Masonry)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! А как можно вывести блоки мозаикой, если они разной не только высоты, но и ширины? Нашел решение для блоков, у которых ширина отличается ровно в два раза. А как быть с блоками произвольной ширины? Нужно сверстать такое:[image: Пример]

Comment: Похожий [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526047/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD). В комментариях есть примеры реализации

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте display: inline-block